# MySQLException 'Foreign key constraint' on :await AddToRoleAsync(User, "Admin"); -> Identity tables ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I am using the Identity system in ASP.NET Core 6. The following code adds role into the `AspNetRoles` table, and adds a user into the `AspNetUsers` table. But it raises an exception when it comes to `AddToRoleAsync` method.

Code:

```
// Create Member Role
result = await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Member"));

if (!result.Succeeded)
    return 2;  // log an error message here

// Create Member User
newid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

var memberUser = new ApplicationUser
                     {
                         Id = newid,
                         UserName = "mem@a.ca",
                         Email = "mem@a.ca",
                         Fname = "The",
                         Lname = "Member",
                         EmailConfirmed = true
                     };

result = await userManager.CreateAsync(memberUser, "Password1!");

if (!result.Succeeded)
     return 3;  // log an error message here

// Assign user to Member role (FAILS)
result = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(memberUser, "Member");

if (!result.Succeeded)
     return 4;  // log an error message here <--- Goes here.
```

Exception raised:

> MySqlException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dbname`.`aspnetuserroles`, CONSTRAINT `FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `aspnetusers` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

Any suggestions or solutions?

Comment: Either the user has not been created yet or has a different id that you have in memberUser variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here object got inserted into db is used to assign role. They have same id. And bychecking database, I can find AspNetUsers table got new user. Not sure what is the reason.